# Get value from another sheets and put it in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm new to vba. I want to get all state and city list from another sheet. Then put it in State and City array. But I got error at state array, 
Run-time error '13'. Type mismatch.

```
Dim State() As String
Dim City() As String
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("State&City").Select
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
->State() = Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
City() = Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value
```

Comment: Have you tried defining your arrays to hold the ranges as `Variant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something along these lines:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("State&City")
Dim State As Variant, City as Variant
Dim LastRow As Long

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    State = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    City = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
End With
```

- So we pulled values into a `Variant` array
- We used an explicit sheet reference and avoided `.Select`

Note: These are two-dimensional arrays, so in above case you can refer to an item like `.Range("C2") = State(1,1)` or for the nth item: `.Range("C2") = State(n,1)`

---

**Alternatively:**

Pull the values into a single array, e.g.: `StateCity`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("State&City")
Dim StateCity as variant
Dim LastRow As Long

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    StateCity = .Range("A2:B" & LastRow)
End With
```

You can now refer to the nth state with:

```
.Range("C2") = StateCity (n,1)
```

Or refer to the nth city with:

```
.Range("C2") = StateCity (n,2)
```

Comment: How do I call the array? I try to put the first state in the same worksheet in C2.
 Range("C2") = State(1) and its shows error.